# How to send emails via SMTP to Outlook & .live domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, outlook

I am building an SaaS application with PHP's codeigniter framework.
 I'm using PHP mail function to Send emails, it works fine with Gmail but not working with anything else i don't why.
 So i used SMTP library to send emails but again I'm unable to send emails to Outlook and .LIVE domain emails.
 Any suggestions, i want to send Confirmation emails, reports etc to outlook emails from my admin panel of website.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i send email use phpmailer.
you can download source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

```
function for_mail($email,$title,$content) {

  $sn   = 'youremailhere';
  $pwd  = 'yuurpassword';
  $host = "emailhost";

  include_once("Public/PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $address =    $email;
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host = $host;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = $sn;
  $mail->Password = $pwd;
  $mail->Port=25;
  $mail->From = $sn;
  $mail->FromName = "TeamIn";
  $mail->AddAddress("$address", "");
  $mail->AddReplyTo("", "");
  $mail->IsHTML(true); 
  $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; 
  $mail->Subject = $title; 
  $mail->Body = $content; 

  if(!$mail->Send())
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```